# Unknown "hiccups" after react tree reconciliation - analyzing Chrome devtools

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I've got a React-Redux app which connect to a websocket server, poll realtime data and display to the user. When tested it with Chrome's devtools, I got the following:

[image]

Now, I can see 6 major "bumps" which indicates 6 times the app got and rendered new data. What I don't understand is what happening in each rendering section.

The part of the "function call" is correlated to the section in "User Timing" where react does tree reconciliation (actually, it does it three times in each of these calls for some reason).

But what's happening right after that? What are all those "Animation frame fired" sections? Those are mostly anonymous functions, so I can't tell which part they belong, or why are they ending with a "Forced reflow"?

Answer (score 0):

Likely an incompatibility between React-Popper and React 16+.  The popper instance seems to be rescheduling its bounds calculation repeatedly, probably because that library relies on very specific undocumented timing of React's lifecycle methods.